# How do you import .code-snippets files in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

My team is trying to come up with a way to maintain a team .code-snippets file. We'd also like this file to be stored within a repo. However, VSCode has no "Import Snippets" option, as far as I can tell, and there is no clear documentation as to where the file needs to be stored.

My questions:

1. How can you import a .code-snippets file?
2. Can it be stored in src/ directory or is there some magic "workspace" folder that VSCode maintains?

*Please note*: I'm not asking how to create a .code-snippets file. I'm wondering what best practices are for sharing one between a group of people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can you import a .code-snippets file?

Just copy & paste your `team.code-snippets` file to the project's `.vscode/` directory. If there is no such directory then create one.

> ...is there some magic "workspace" folder that VSCode maintains?

Yes. That's the `.vscode` directory.

> We'd also like this file to be stored within a repo.

You can commit/push the `.vscode/` directory to version control.

---

There are a [more details here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_creating-your-own-snippets) about creating your own snippets.

Comment: I guess this works... I was confused because VSCode workspaces can be one package, multiple packages... basically however you define it. So I wasn't clear on where the .vscode/ directory actually needed to go. And there are global snippets as well, so it wasn't totally clear what to do. 

In the end, I just made a .vscode/ directory for each package I wanted it in, and just copied the snippets file into all of those.

Comment: for global snippet, in window, you can paste file into folder C:\Users\[your_user]\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets